# macros vba need to apply formula to column till it has value in the last row

Tags: vba, if-statement, formula

**I need to apply "IF "formula in whole C column till has last value in the sheet using VBA .**

but i am getting error 438 if i use the following code . Plz help me

```
Sub test11()

With Sheets("Sheet")
        .Range("c1:c" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(B1="",TRIM(A1),TRIM(B1))"

    End With



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your sheet name is `Sheet` or `Sheet1`? And OP mentioned Sheet name is `Sheet2`. That removes one error. Secondly, you need to set `D` column as `.Cells(.Rows.Count,"D").End(xlUp).Row)` instead of `A` column.

Here is a very ugly code to try out: It takes last used row in count into the `Long` variable. Then set the range accordingly for setting up the `formula` using `AutoFill`.

```
Sub test11()
Dim l As Long    

l = Sheets(1).Range("d1:d" & Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Count
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("d1").Formula = "=IF(IsNull(B1),TRIM(A1),TRIM(B1))"
        .Range("d1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("d1:d" & l), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sheetname is sheet2 . But i tried it . I am getting error runtime error 1004

Comment: @newjenn I am doubtful of your question title, can you clarify please. Do you want to check if column `A` cell is not empty and then apply the formula to column `C` cell?

Comment: Thanks dude for your effort . It is giving error 1004 autofill class range failed . But if i replace in the condition ISnull to """" , it is working fine .

Comment: Use `IsBlank()` instead of `IsNull()`

Comment: @newjenn It is a typo since the code was written in VBA. `IsNull` is VBA, doesn't support in Excel Sheet formula. So you need to use `IsBlank()`. Tested and error proof ;) Thanks iDevelop for showing the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems a bit strange, but this works:

```
Sub test11()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(.Range("c1"), .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) = "=IF(B1="""",TRIM(A1),TRIM(B1))"
    End With
End Sub
```

You need to double the quotes within quotes in VBA.
Another variant:

```
Sub test12()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Intersect(.Range("c1").CurrentRegion, .Range("C:C")).Formula = "=IF(B1="""",TRIM(A1),TRIM(B1))"
    End With
End Sub
```