# Apply formula to column through macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14031794/4200461) but the code is throwing Run-time errors on line 5 and 6

```
Sub CalculateTAT()
  Dim l As Long
  l = Sheets(2).Range("A1:A" & Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Count
  With Sheets("Call Logs")
    .Range("R1").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISBLANK(I1),ISBLANK(F1)),"",I1-F1)"
    .Range("R1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("R1:R" & l), Type:=xlFillDefault
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There are many Run-time errors. Can you please provide more info about these errors. For example exact error message/Error Number?

Comment: The `Destination:=Range("R1:R" & l)` parameter for `.AutoFill` is missing the `Destination:=.Range("R1:R" & l)` prefix that would associate it to the parent `With Sheets("Call Logs")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use quotes within a quoted string, (e.g. the formula), you need to double them up.

```
.Range("R1:R" & l).Formula = "=IF(OR(ISBLANK(I1),ISBLANK(F1)),"""",I1-F1)"
```

You can fill the range with the formula all at once. No need to use `.AutoFill` in a separate operation.

*Addendum:* This might be a bit better

```
 l = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Since you are starting at row 1 there is no need to look at anything but the last non-blank row in the column. Unless you are mixing and matching `.XLSX` and `.XLS` worksheets, `Rows.Count` will always mean the last row; there is no need to give it a parent like `Sheets(2).Rows.Count`. You would have to have it defined in an `.XLSX` and used in a `.XLS` in order for it to generate an error.